# Cycles rendering circles with strange feathering

Tags: modeling, rendering, cycles-render-engine

[image]Circles and other round objects are coming out with strange indentations on the upper most parts, and protrusions on the bottom. Everything in the project is the default blender project, except the light is increased, and the cube has been replaced with a circle. I have tried increasing the number of samples and playing with the pixel filter. Nothing seems to make it much better, if at all.

any ideas?[image]